# Reset a MacBook to original settings without losing the files

Tags: macos, macbook

I've effed up an installation of *at least two* software on my Mac. XAMPP and MAMP. I'm pretty sure those two shouldn't mix.

Anyway, if all else fails, is there a way to restore my MacBook to factory conditions *without* erasing all the files in here, and without using a disc or something? No, I was not foresighted enough to set a Time Machine backup or anything.

Windows 8 has a Refresh option - refreshes the OS, keeps the files. I wonder if Mac has something similar?

P.S. My MacBook Pro is 13 inch, Mid 2012 version.

Comment: I know with windows install you can have the option to put the contents of your existing hard drive into a folder named "windows.old" and the new OS install will be put around that folder, and If I can recall, the last time I installed OS X onto a hard drive that already had files on it I got the option to back up everything that I had on said hard drive into a seperate device or a partition on the HDD. Dunno if this is still a feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a disc or a backup, use [OS X Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718).

Comment: Will this allow me to keep my files? I'm a little iffy about this - internet is spotty where I'm at.